# Cardinal Arithmetic, foundations and constructive math

Tags: cardinal-arithmetic, constructive-mathematics, continuum-hypothesis, foundations, lo.logic

This is not my area but a question occurred to me that I can not find the answer to. There is a very strong **axiom of constructibility** which *ironically* gives us highly non-constructive math (**GCH** is one of its implications). What would be an equally strong axiom in the opposite direction? And I mean direction in a philosophical sense, so what would be the strongest axiom that constructivists/intuitionists would approve of?

My first idea was to find the largest $\kappa$ such that $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_{\kappa}$ is consistent with **ZF** but this set is unbounded ($\kappa$ can be any finite number) and $2^{\aleph_0} < \aleph_{\omega}$. Which brings up the question, how much fundamental difference are there between **CH** and $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_{118}$ for example?

Comment: `$2^{\aleph_0}$` need not be smaller than `$\aleph_\omega$`.  You may be thinking of the theorem that it cannot be *equal* to `$\aleph_\omega$`, but it might well be larger.

Comment: How does the axiom of constructibility give us non-constructive math? $\:$

Comment: Building off of Ricky's comment, I'd argue that in fact the presence of GCH is actually a reasonably constructive consequence of the axiom of constructibility (V=L). The reason that GCH holds assuming V=L is that from V=L we can actually define a precise well-ordering of the reals (in fact, of the entire universe, but that's a separate issue) and show that this well-ordering has order type $\omega_1$. This basically requires us to (1) determine the real number satisfying some first-order property, and (2) iterate that procedure through all the countable ordinals. (cont'd)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "constructive," since that word can have many different meanings, but certainly this reason for GCH holding (in fact, all of V=L) seems fairly constructive, at least relative to what set theory tends to involve.

Comment: @Ricky, well **GCH** implies **AC** ...

Comment: @Noah, my understanding is that the model for **V=L** done by Godel is "constructive" but the theory itself (which is always much bigger than any single model ...) is not. 

Comment: @Najdorf: Your last comment adds some urgency to Noah's request that you explain your terminology. You have said that a certain countable set of sentences ("the theory itself") is "much bigger" than a certain  proper class ("the model for $V=L$ done by Gödel"). You have also applied the word "constructive" to two things of very different types, a theory and a model, which leads me to think you have (at least) two meanings in mind for this word.

Comment: @Najdorf, the point of my comment is that things like GCH, AC, etc. are not "inherently" non-constructive (for a broad enough notion of "constructive"). To elaborate, the usual reason given for thinking of AC as non-constructive is roughly that it entails the existence of undefinable sets of reals. However, this isn't actually true: assuming V=L, every set of reals is definable (from an ordinal). What this means to me is that the idea that "AC is inherently nonconstructive" is flawed, or at least requires further explanation. Similar arguments apply to GCH, etc. (cont'd)

Comment: See, for instance, Section 7.2 of "On arbitrary sets and ZFC" by Jose Ferreiros (http://www.math.ucla.edu/~asl/bsl/1703/1703-002.ps), which points out that AC loses some of its nonconstructive flavor in the context of V=L. Also, I second Andreas' question about theory vs. model - in every sense I'm aware of, any model of ZFC+V=L must be at least as large as the theory.

Comment: @Blass I think you are right in your first comment. 



Comment: @all: I call an axiom **AX** non-constructive if it has non-constructive consequences in everyday classical mathematics we use. I thought that was the normal understanding of the term. 

Comment: Najdorf, isn't any axiom non-constructive on that criterion? After all, the law of excluded middle is classically valid, and so any axiom has excluded middle as a consequence in classical logic. 

Comment: @Najdorf Do you consider the law of excluded middle as being constructive?

Comment: @Najdorf Especially in light of your rejection of some of Andrej's observations about constructive mathematics, I'm still confused: what is a "non-constructive consequence?"

Comment: Law of excluded middle is non-constructive. I have doubts about MP as well, if $A$ and $A \to B$ but it took a trillion years to get from $A$ to $B$  would that be constructive? I have realized that I use constructive in a much stronger form than anyone else here. For example, I have a class of graphs with $\chi = 5$ but the proof is classical, then I get a 5-coloring algorithm of order $O(|G|^{|G|})$. To my mind the algorithm is progress but still not constructive. In short being constructive without being computable in some sensible sense of the word does not make sense to me ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cardinal arithmetic is the wrong thing to think about, constructively speaking. Here are some facts about constructive mathematics (when I say "may" that means there is a model validating the fact):

- Cardinals cannot be shown to be linearly ordered.
- The ordinals may form a set.
- A subset of a finite set need not be finite.
- A subset of a countable set need not be countable.
- It is conistent to assume that there is an embedding $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}$.
- It is consistent to assume that every set is a quotient of a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, for example $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$.

So, I think you're going in the wrong direction. Size is simply not measured the same way intuitionistically. "Extra" axioms considered by constructive mathematics can broadly be divided into several groups:

1. **Fragments of the law of excluded middle**, such as Limited Principle of Omniscience and Markov Principle, which bring us closer to classical mathematics.
2. **Choice principles**, such as countable choice, dependent choice, function choice, which bring in some amount of the axiom of choice. Another such axiom is Aczel's presentation axiom, which states that every set is covered by one for which choice holds.
3. **Continuity principles**, such as "every function between complete separable spaces is continuous", which are typically incompatible with the law of excluded middle. Another such axiom is the Fan principle, whose important consequence is that the closed interval is compact .
4. **Induction principles**, which guarantee existence of sets defined by various induction schemata.
5. **Computability principles**, stating that "everything is computable" in some form. The best known such principle is the formal Church's thesis.

The induction principles vaguely correspond to large cardinal axioms, and so they are perhaps closest to what you are asking for. A *predicative* constructivist will worry about existence of powersets, so he is going to consider various other axioms that bring in powersets in a limited form, but let us not get into that.

Comment: Under what assumptions do the ordinals form a set?

Comment: Alright that was helpful but I still have some issues: (1) When you say there are models for your first list of statements, what is the base system of constructive math you are working with? (2) Throughout the whole discussion I am assuming a degree of reasonableness, an axiom stating the fact that a finite set can have non-finite subsets or that we have an embedding $\mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{N}$ are not resonable (3) I might be mistaken but I thought that intuitionists did not like Church's thesis ... 

Comment: @David: a realizability topos validates "trichotomous ordinals form a set", see http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0340

Comment: @Najdorf: If you're going to arbitrarily declare some constructively possible phenomena "not reasonable", then you should give some hints about how much classical mathematics your notion of "reasonable" includes. We now know that it includes the non-constructive principles that $R$ can't embed in $N$ and that subsets of finite sets are finite, but we have no idea what else it might include. So people trying to answer your question are left to simply guess what you're willing to admit as "reasonable". 

Comment: @Najdorf: (1) the base system does not matter so much, it could be higher-order intuitionistic logic (i.e., the internal language of a topos), or some variant of intuitionistic set theory. (2) I agree that having an embedding $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}$ is unreasonable, but it is unavodiable that a finite set should have non-finite subsets. In fact, the statement "every subset of a singleton is finite" implies excluded middle.

Comment: @Najdorf What is unreasonable about the fact that a finite set might have non-finite subsets? A finite set is a set $A$ such that there exists (constructively!) a natural number $n$ and a bijection $[n]\simeq A$. Now consider the subset $X$ of the singleton $\{0\}$ such that $X$ contains $0$ if and only if GHC holds. Classically $X$ is either empty or equal to $\{0\}$, but constructively there is no way to find a bijection between $X$ and some standard finite set $[n]$.
A set which is not finite does not need to be infinite either.

Comment: @Najdorf:  (3) I am not saying that all intuitionists accept all axioms I listed. Actually, the constructive mathematicians I know are mostly *convervative* -- they do not want to assume *any* extra axioms, except perhaps dependent choice. In any case, constructive mathematics is a *base* on top of which one can usefully explore other kinds of mathematics, so it is not unusual to consider various axioms out of sheer curiosity. You don't have to go all philosophical all the time.

Comment: @Guillaume: in my experience the Brouwerian counterexamples do not help explain anything to classical mathematicians. You see, if you already believe that GCH either holds or not, then your reasoning is vacuous. It is better to provide a proof that some statement implies excluded middle. Here: a finite set is either empty or inhabited (it is bijective to a unique $[n]$, and so se just observe whether $n = 0$). Consider the subset $\lbrace 1 \mid p\rbrace$ where $p$ is any truth value. If this set is empty then $\lnot p$, if it is inhabited then $p$. Therefore $p$ or $\lnot p$, excluded middle.

Comment: @Andrej: I was assuming that if someone believe that GHC either holds or not then he probably also believe in excluded middle anyway. But I see your point, one can know that excluded middle is constructively problematic but not recognize a particular instance of it.

Comment: Exactly, and also it is misleading to offer specific statements whose status is yet unknown but could be resolved in the future. This makes it look like you are confusing the truth value of a statement with our knowledge of it. In fact, this is precisely the reason why I find Brouwerian counter-examples to be a really poor way of explaining intuitionistic mathematics. There is a difference between something being true and us knowing it is true, and Brouweian counter-examples ask you to forget about the difference.

Comment: Thanks, Andrej. It's relevant for a possible constructive extension of a theorem I'm working on.

Comment: @Robert: you are welcome. If you are really combining ordinal numbers and constructive math, I definitely recommend reading Paul Taylor's JSL paper on the subject.

Comment: @Andrej, @Guillaume: In those cases I would take issue with the way you define the subsets which depend on an odd black box. What you have is not a fixed subset, it can be different things in the future, it is essentially a random variable. 

Comment: @Najdorf: the same criticism applies to classical mathematics. We are not forming any strange subsets, only ones that classical mathematicians do too. You keep changing the rules of the game every time we tell you something you do not like. It does not work that way, we are not cheating, that is how things are. Lastly, statements like "your subset is different things in the future, it is essentially a random variable" do not mean anything. You have to make them mathematically precise. I was not basing my arguments on a notion of time or randomness. My proof is water tight.

Comment: @Guillaume: see how people get confused by the Brouwerian counterexamples? It is best not to use them. It legitimizes funny talk about "future" and "random variables".

Comment: @Andrej: I am very sorry for the lack of clarity, I have not thought about these things and strangely enough I think I use constructive in a stronger form than anyone else here which just worsens the matters. The subset/Random Variable is not a *real subset*, so if the non-finite subsets of a finite set are only of that type then I am fine with the original statement. The next question is whether what I call *real subset* can be formalized in any sense or not ... 

Comment: @Najdorf: only you can know whether the thing you call "real subset" can be formalized. I suspect you means something like "decidable subset". That is insufficient to do mathematics. Let me give you an example which should worry you. Let $p : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a polynomial. Consider the set of its zeroes $Z = \lbrace x \mid p(x) = 0\rbrace$ and then the intersection $Z \cap \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. It is a subset of $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$. It is unprovable intuitionistically that $Z \cap \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ is finite. So, in your view that set must not be "real". But then what is left?

Comment: Alright that example clarified things a bit. But I am fine with unprovabally finite subsets of a finite set. My initial thought after reading your statement was that, there is a freakish model where a finite set had a non-finite subset (that would is stupid but from my experience you can't just call something obviously stupid and move one hence my confusion).

Comment: Also above I said that my idea of constructivism is that it should be practically computable (I mentioned MP in addition to the law of excluded middle). I have no idea if this is even a topic of discussion in constructive/intuitionist circles but if you look at it from a programming point of view it is the most natural definition.

Comment: Any topos whose object of truth values has more than two truth values will contain freakish subsets of the singleton. Consider the Grothendieck topos $Sh(\mathbb{R})$ of sheaves over $\mathbb{R}$. The subsets of the singleton $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ correspond to the open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, but only two of those, $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$, are finite. There is also a computational reason why you should not expect subsets of a finite set to be finite. Consider the intersection of a c.e. set and a finite set. Why do you expect to be able to produce a finite list of its elements?

Comment: Yes, "constructive" mathematicians are concerned with practical computation, very much so. I happen to be concerned with practical computation. But I am not a constructive mathematician.